# Convert UIImage to Bitmap in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to convert a UIImage to Bitmap in iOS, Bitmap conversion in android is very easy by using BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray() but in iOS I am not able to find any method.

Comment: A UIImage can be directly convert it to a jpg/png bitmap or the raw data bitmap, or are you are looking for a Windows (DIB) `.bmp` as that is a different story

Comment: no i don't want to save it as .bmp, i want to call a method which takes Bitmap as parameter. Something like  public static int[] getEachImageDifferently(Bitmap bmp)

Comment: So your function accepts a Windows/DIB `Bitmap`? i.e. is that `Bitmap` class coming from System.Drawing?

Comment: Bitmap class of System.Drawing